# java attach file from virtual filesystem to email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, nio, jimfs

I am using a virtual filesystem and I'd like to attach a file from it to an email. However, the MimeBodyPart object only takes Files, which don't work on a default filesystem like jimfs. See my code below, where I get an UnsupportedOperation exception when I try to convert to file.

```
public Email attach(Path file){
    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart()
    attachment.attachFile(file.toFile())
    attachments.add(attachment)
    return this
}
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using? Is the unsupportedOperation occurred on attaching the file to MimeBodyPart or File.toFile() that does not support virtual filesystem?

Comment: the file.toFile() call is throwing the unsupported exception, because jimfsPath does not implement that method. I'm using java 8. As far as I can tell MimeBodyPart only knows how to interact with Files, not Path objects.

Comment: Ok So if I understand you correctly, you need to use the jimfs API, write the file into the filesystem and then attach to the MimeBodyPart class. The advanced method is to "extends" File and override the methods which would allow dynamic stream of the content from jimfs. However, I would stick to the simple approach first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since jimfs files aren't **really** files, you can't use the File APIs.

A simple workaround is to use [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html), which will copy the data.

A better approach would be to write your own PathDataSource that's similar to [FileDataSource](https://github.com/javaee/activation/blob/master/activation/src/main/java/javax/activation/FileDataSource.java) but uses [Files.newInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) instead of FileInputStream.  Then attach the file using:

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new PathDataSource(path)));
mbp.setFileName(path.getFileName().toString());
mbp.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
```

Comment: Where does that PathdataSource object come from? I'm having trouble finding the docs (I see FileDataSource)

Comment: You write it, based on FileDataSource.

Comment: This works, but see jmehrens's comment on Colin's answer for a cleaner solution. Thanks Bill!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever this `MimeBodyPart` API is really *ought* to have an option to use a `Path` so that you could just use the Jimfs file directly, but since the `java.nio.file` APIs require Java 7 and don't work on Android yet many libraries unfortunately don't support `Path` yet.

`toFile()` can never work for a Jimfs file, or for *any* file that isn't on the default file system, because the `File` class can only represent files on the default file system. So yeah, you'd need to copy the Jimfs file to the real file system to use this `attachFile` method.

If the `MimeBodyPart` API had an option for using a `URL` or `URI` for the attachment, you would probably be able to use that plus `file.toUri()[.toURL()]`. Or if it could use, say, an `InputStream` you could obviously get one of those from the file and use it instead.

Comment: Looks like I might be in the market for a new mail api :/

Comment: @Steve Use [javax.activation.URLDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/URLDataSource.html).  Then use the example code from @bill-shannon but use this `mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new URLDataSource(path.toUri().toURL())))` as the source.

Comment: If jimfs provides real URLs that are usable with URLConnection, that would work too.

Comment: I have a related question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378292/java-uri-pointing-to-virtual-filesystem. Turning my path into a URI seems to work for emails, but not for zipfiles :/

Comment: @BillShannon: Jimfs does indeed provide `URL`s that are usable with `URLConnection`. Though I think your solution is a good one.